# Splitting a string by a defined length with python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string..

```
lyrics = "Never gonna give you up Never gonna let you down Never gonna run around and desert you Never gonna make you cry Never gonna say goodbye Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you"
```

I only want to display 23 characters on a line:

```
Never gonna give you up
Never gonna let you dow
n Never gonna run aroun
d and desert you Never 
gonna make you cry Neve
r gonna say goodbye Nev
er gonna tell a lie and
hurt you
```

(hopefully I didn't mess that up, let's pretend there is 24 characters on each line, I am very sleepy I can't even count)

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to split words like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through `re.findall` function.

```
>>> import re
>>> lyrics = "Never gonna give you up Never gonna let you down Never gonna run around and desert you Never gonna make you cry Never gonna say goodbye Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you"
>>> for i in re.findall(r'.{1,23}', lyrics):
    print i


Never gonna give you up
 Never gonna let you do
wn Never gonna run arou
nd and desert you Never
 gonna make you cry Nev
er gonna say goodbye Ne
ver gonna tell a lie an
d hurt you
```